# point to class by reference

Tags: actionscript-3

My application has a number of identical AS3 class instances:

```
var Pan1:Panel = new Panel(etc);
var Pan2:Panel = new Panel(etc);
var Pan3:Panel = new Panel(etc);
var Pan4:Panel = new Panel(etc);
```

One of these instances is manipulated at a time. I'd like to refer to this 'active' instance like:

```
var ActivePanel:Panel = Pan3;
```

But in such a way, that when I change: `ActivePanel.property1`, this also automatically changes the original instance (i.e. `Pan3.property1`).

I've searched Google for an answer, but I guess with the wrong query... Can anyone please point out how to do this?

Thanks a lot!

David

Comment: It should work exactly as you described as both variables are just references to the original instance.

Comment: And it does! 

Note to self: "next time check your code..." </self>

Thank you James for your response. A mistake in my code, and a few hours wasted. Thanks again!

Comment: This is still showing up as an "unanswered question."

Answer (score -2):

You will need to extend the panel class to create a new class (called clonedLabel for e.g) and create a clone method...

This is some psuedo code ...

```
<mx:Panel>

     <mx:Script>
         <![CDATA[

            public function clone():ClonedPanel{

                  var clonedLabel:ClonedPanel= new ClonedPanel();

                  // code here to construct new Panel
                  .
                  .
                  .

                  return clonedLabel;

         ]]>
     </mx:Script>


<mx:Panel>
```